# How to stretch background image on Script task HTML Email (c#, HTML, CSS)

Tags: c#, html, css, script-task

I have a script task that creates an HTML email and I can add a background image but I am having trouble getting the image to stretch to size.  Everything I have read suggests using CSS but I am not very versed at HTML/CSS and even less sure of how to implement this in a script task.  Here is my code:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sdaGetValidation.Fill(dt);   

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<html><body {background='http://myImage.jpg'>");
sb.AppendLine("\t" + "<body>");
sb.AppendLine("\t\t" + "<table>");
sb.Append("<table border='1px' solid line black cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' ");
sb.Append("style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;'>");

sb.Append("\t\t" + "<tr>");

foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", dc.ColumnName);
}

sb.AppendLine("<tr>");

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.Append("\t\t\t" + "<tr>");

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        string cellValue = dr[dc] != null ? dr[dc].ToString() : "";
        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", cellValue);
    }

    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
}

sb.AppendLine("\t\t\t" + "</table>");
sb.AppendLine("\t" + "</body>");
sb.AppendLine("</html>");

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

This line gets the image to show but it tiles:

```
sb.AppendLine("<html><body background='http://myImage.jpg'>");
```

I'm hoping this will be a quick win for someone who knows HTML better than I.  Once again I keep reading that I'll need to use CSS but not even sure if that is true or how to implement CSS in this situation.

Comment: Not sure what you need it for, but you could try: `sb.AppendLine("<html><body style='background-image:url(http://myImage.jpg);background-size:cover;'>")`

Comment: I'm trying to use a company background image and due to the HTML table being so long it's causing the image to tile, either that or it's just trying to fill the screen.  I would just like to have it stretch so no matter what screen the email is viewed on it looks essentially the same.  Unfortunately a required server is down so I can't test this solution yet but will asap and mark as answer it it works.  I want to say I have tried this but my syntax might have been off...

Comment: The code itself seems to add `<body>` twice, just a heads up :)

Comment: That could be my issue!!!

Comment: So removed the second <body> tag and pasted your code in and it's the same thing where it tiles the image!!! So frustrating!!!

Comment: That should work... does anything change if you do '100% 100%' instead of 'cover' ?

Comment: Oh, maybe it's because the body itself is looping? What happens if you do: `sb.AppendLine("<html><body style='background-image:url(image);background-size:cover;height:800px;'>");`

Comment: Still the same thing!

Comment: That's odd... I think this is too tough to spot the error in with the code on hand, does adding `sb.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE html><html>........."` do anything ? I guess not...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the style attribute within the body tag:

```
<body style="background-image:url('http://something.com'); background-size:cover;">
```

Comment: Still the same thing.... Do you think it's because the email is being opened in Outlook???

Comment: try this: `<body style="background-image:url('http://something.com'); background-size:cover; background-repeat:none;">` Maybe it's repeating.

Comment: Yeah it does look like the image is repeating (tiling) and even after adding this still getting same results :(

Comment: I think it does have to do with the email client(outlook)!